# Using C# Socket class and losing formatting in a Word file

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, syncfusion

I am using that code, which will print a document using a network printer:

```
 Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
 socket.NoDelay = true;

 IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
 IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ip, someport);
 socket.Connect(ipEndPoint);


 socket.Send(_byteArray);
 socket.Close();
```

That code works, but I am losing the formats in my Word document.

Where does the Byte-Array come from?

I am using the Syncfusion-library(relevant code snippet):

```
... someMethod(){

WordDocument word = new WordDocument();
//... some code
word.Save(myMemoryStream, FormatType.Docx);
_byteArray=myMemoryStream.ToArray(); //Comment on Syncfusion-library: "Writes the stream contents to a byte array, regardless of the System.IO.MemoryStream.Position"

word.Close();
}
```

What can I do here ?

Comment: you don't lose data when using TCP, the problem might be related to how you get the data and how you interpret it on the receiving side which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Are you sure byteArray contains a word doc, and not just the text?

Comment: If you are loosing the formats then a stream is defaulting to Ascii Encoding instead of UTF8 encoding.  It is not occurring in the code you posted.  TCP will not modify data.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code, may be this helps ?!

Comment: May be this helps too, when providing that byte array to an user agent(FileContentResult File(byte[] fileContents, string contentType, string fileDownloadName);)using asp.net mvc) we need to add the contentType like this for getting the right document for the client: "application/pdf" ,excel: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml‌​.sheet", word: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessin‌​gml.document" . May be this helps more than referencing the library.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that, you might not be installed the fonts (which are used in the Word document) in your production environment. If so, kindly install all the used fonts in your production environment to resolve the reported issue.

If you aren't modify any of Word document content, then you can try the below code.

```
 // Open Word document using FileStream.
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("input.docx", FileMode.Open);
// Copy file stream to MemoryStream.
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
// Gets byte array from memory stream of file.
byte[] temp = memoryStream.ToArray();
```

If you’re facing the same issue means, then the used fonts in the input document might not be installed in your production environment so, install all the used fonts to resolve the issue.

If you’re not facing the reported issue in this approach, then kindly share your codes along with input and resultant Word document from your end to validate further.